# Express crashes when GET path regex has named capture groups: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Layer.match

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to handle a GET request and match some information from the URL. Consider this example:

```
const REGEX_QUERY = /^\/?house\/(?<street>[a-z]+)\/(?<house>[0-9]+)$/i;
const REGEX_QUERY_NO_NAMES = /^\/house\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)$/i;

app.get([REGEX_QUERY], async (req, res, next)=>{
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    const match = REGEX_QUERY.exec(req.path);
    res.send(`You are looking for house #${match.groups.house} in ${match.groups.street} street`);
});
```

The error you get if you try to visit the URL, such as `/house/evergreen/25` is a 500 error that occurs even before the path handler runs. The full stack is this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Layer.match (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:147:20)
    at matchLayer (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:585:18)
    at next (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:15)
    at SendStream.error (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at SendStream.error (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/send/index.js:417:12)
    at next (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/send/index.js:731:16)
    at onstat (/MY_EXPRESS_PROJECT/node_modules/send/index.js:720:14)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
```

If I just remove the named groups - so use the `.get([REGEX_QUERY_NO_NAMES] ...` the rest of the code works and will send, for example:

```
You are looking for house #25 in evergreen street
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you give also an example of the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that named groups are not supported by express `<=4.x`, see [this open issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4277) (looks like it's [planned for v5](https://github.com/expressjs/express/milestone/11) tho).

For now, you can use named parameters with [`:` prefix](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#named-parameters), for example:

```
app.get(['/house/:house([a-z]+)/:street([0-9]+)'], function( req, res ) {
    res.send(`You are looking for house #${req.params.house} in ${req.params.street} street`);
});
```

Testing:

```
GET /house/evergreen/25
```

Matched:

[image: Express router]

See:

- [express-route-tester](https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/)
- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters
- https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, I didn't know about these at all. Nor did I know about this way to match params from URL.